# GitLab-CI and node.js - how to start a local server then run tests?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've set up GitLab-CI, and am writing my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to run my tests. My app is written in node.js, and the file looks like this:

```
before_script:
  - npm install
  - node server.js

stages:
  - test

job_name:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test
```

I'm having trouble actually starting the server then running tests, as `node server.js` creates a foreground process that never exists unless you do so manually. Is there a way to start the server, then move on, then stop it once the tests have finished?

Or am I actually doing this wrong, and should my server get started in the tests themselves? Everything I read just says "start node then in another terminal run your tests against your local server" but this is obviously pointless in an automated CI system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the exact same setup, with gitlab-ci docker runner. You don't need to launch the `node server.js` before launching your tests, you can let your test runner handle it. I use Mocha + Chai (with chai-http). You can also use supertest to do the same.

It look for available ports before each test so you don't end up with conflicting port.

Here is how it looks :

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
// Interesting part
var app = require('../server/server');
var loginUser = require('./login.js');
var auth = {token: ''};

chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();

describe('/users', function() {

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    loginUser(auth, done);
  });

  it('returns users as JSON', function(done) {
    // This is what launch the server
    chai.request(app)
    .get('/api/users')
    .set('Authorization', auth.token)
    .then(function (res) {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.should.be.json;
      res.body.should.be.instanceof(Array).and.have.length(1);
      res.body[0].should.have.property('username').equal('admin');
      done();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return done(err);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: can you show me your gitlab-ci.yml? i also do the same but don't know how to run test before build for production

Comment: This has little to do with the question.

Perhaps the tests that are being run are running in browser, so you cannot start the server from within the test itself.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use `nohup` command to launch your server in background.

`$ nohup node server.js &`

( `&` at the end of line is used to return to the prompt)

In your example:

```
before_script:
  - npm install
  - nohup node server.js &

stages:
  - test

job_name:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test
```

Comment: This is the actual answer. Thanks, MrP!